# (WindowsIoT) Visual Studio 2015 RC Cannot find connection on Subnet

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iot

In Visual Studio 2015 RC, When trying to remote connect to another machine for remote diagnostics ( or to deploy an app to a Raspberry Pi ), Whilst searching for Remote connections it fails and returns with "Found 0 Connections on my subnet" even though there are 2 devices currently visible to the IoT Core Watcher.

If we ignore this and set the IP of the machine and build -> Deploy, It will fail and bring an error up of

```
Error : DEP2100 : Cannot copy the file "FILENAME" to the target machine "IP / Name".
```

Attached is a screenshot of our problems.

[Visual Studio Failing to find devices and IoT Core found 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elYFC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the error: Ethernet was connected to Router not Host PC.
Connecting to Host PC and enabling network sharing works.

Answer (score 0):

The search is not currently working.

Deploying an application by manually providing the IP address is working though. I reviewed the screen shot that you attached. I don't understand why you have entered an address of 169.168.137.79 when the device is at **192**.168.137.79. Is this a typo? Everything else looks ok.

Mark Radbourne (MSFT)